# Understanding System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert

Tags: wpf, converters, implicit-conversion

I've struggled to understand this error for some time and now it's finally breaking something. Here's a dumbed-down sketch of what I'm doing:

My datawrapper class:

```
class DummyWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DummyWrapper() { }

    private T _data;
    public T Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            Notify("Data");
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(DummyWrapper<T> d)
    {
        return d._data;
    }

    ...
}
```

My XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Name="cp" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="foo" Fill="{Binding ElementName=cp, Path=Content}" Height="50" Width="50"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The pertinent bit of my codebehind:

```
DummyWrapper<Brush> dw = new DummyWrapper<Brush>(new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red")));
cp.Content = dw;
```

And of course if this was all working the way I expected I wouldn't be here. The output window shows me this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'WpfTestApplication.DummyWrapper`1[System.Windows.Media.Brush]' 
from type 'DummyWrapper`1' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' 
for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.
```

... and it goes on in that  vein for some time.

Is there something I can do to allow my `DummyWrapper` to be converted automatically (ie w/o supplying a converter in the binding) in this context?

Comment: ...to be clear, it isn't just puking out an error in the output window. It isn't setting the brush at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line of code to

```
var solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush((Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red"));
DummyWrapper<Brush> dw = new DummyWrapper<Brush>(solidColorBrush);
cp.Content = (Brush)dw;
```

You don't want to use `converters` that's fine. `Content` is an object and doing an implicit operator will not just do that unless the `Content` is of type `Brush`. You have to explicitly cast it to `Brush`

> `System.Object` is the type of the Content property.
>   Through inheritance there's already an implicit conversion to the base
>   type

Comment: Okay. That's weird. I think that my converter wouldn't even have to convert to Brush, just to DummyWrapper<Brush>. Thanks; I should have seen that.

Comment: Well, I just don't see the reason why you have to do implicit converters without using the converters especially if you are using WPF. They are built for that reason.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. I'd built a collection of wrappers and I was hoping it could transparently masquerade as a collection of the underlying data type. I see that it cannot.